# Probability of getting the correct direction, given you get the same answer

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

> A town is composed of $2/5$ out of town couples and $3/5$ in town
>   couples. If a couple is from out of town, the probability that the
>   husband and wife will give you the correct directions independently is
>   $3/4$. If the couple is from in town, they will always give you the
>   correct direction independently of each other. Suppose you ask a
>   random couple for directions. If both the husband and wife give you
>   the same direction, what is the probability that this direction is
>   correct?

I've done $X$ = (probability that direction is correct)/(probability they give you the same direction).

(probability that direction is correct) = $3/5 + (2/5)(3/4)(3/4) = 33/40$

(probability they give you the same direction) = $3/5 + (2/5)(3/4)(3/4)+(2/5)(1/4)(1/4) = 17/20$

$X = (33/40)/(17/20) = 33/34$

Does this seem correct? Have I done anything incorrectly?

Comment: What does "give you the correct directions independently" mean?

Comment: @barakmanos The in town husband and wife will each give you the correct direction with probability 1, and each is independent of the other (for probability (1)(1)=1).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is right, but consider to be more precise and use the mathematical expressions and formulas:

What you are looking for is the [conditional probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) $P (A\mid B) $ for
$$A=\text { The couple tells you the right direction.}$$
and
$$B=\text { The husband and the wife are telling the same direction.}$$

Since
$$ P (A\mid B)=\frac{P (A\cap B)}{P (B)}$$
you need at first the probability that the husband and the wife are telling you the same and that this is the right direction. Therefore
$$ P (A\cap B)=\frac{3}{5}+ \frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac {3}{4} \cdot\frac{3}{4}= \frac {33}{40} $$
Secondly, you need
$$ P (B)= \frac{3}{5}+ \frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac {3}{4} \cdot\frac{3}{4}+ \frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac {1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4} =\frac{34}{40}$$
Finally
$$ P (A\mid B)= \frac{33}{34}$$